# Ajax pagination with jQuery & PHP XML API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an Ajax pagination system to display my XML API (SOAP) results.

I have a liittle example that show me how to fetch the reults from a mysql db. But I need to fetch my rezults from XML API & Database.

The example:
jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#results" ).load( "fetch_pages.php"); //load initial records

    //executes code below when user click on pagination links
    $("#results").on( "click", ".pagination a", function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".loading-div").show(); //show loading element
        var page = $(this).attr("data-page"); //get page number from link
        $("#results").load("fetch_pages.php",{"page":page}, function(){ //get content from PHP page
            $(".loading-div").hide(); //once done, hide loading element
        });

    });
});
```

PHP

```
//get total number of records from database for pagination
    $results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM paginate");
    $get_total_rows = $results->fetch_row(); //hold total records in variable
    //break records into pages
    $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);

    //get starting position to fetch the records
    $page_position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

    //SQL query that will fetch group of records depending on starting position and item per page. See SQL LIMIT clause
    $results = $mysqli_conn->query("SELECT id, name, message FROM paginate ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page");

    //Display records fetched from database.

    echo '<ul class="contents">';
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo  $row["id"]. '. <strong>' .$row["name"].'</strong> &mdash; '.$row["message"];
        echo '</li>';
    }  
    echo '</ul>';


    echo '<div align="center">';
    /* We call the pagination function here to generate Pagination link for us. 
    As you can see I have passed several parameters to the function. */
    echo paginate_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows[0], $total_pages);
    echo '</div>';
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loading-div"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" ></div>
<div id="results"><!-- content will be loaded here --></div>
```

I have:

- Variables from XML API: `$boardType[n]` , `$hotelPrices[n]`,
  `$availHotels[n]->rooms[n]->roomCategory;`
- Variables from MYSQL: `$hotelName[n]`, `$hotelAddress[n]`,
  `$img[n][x]` etc..

The code built so far is:

```
//get total number of records from database for pagination
    $results = count($availHotels);
    $get_total_rows = $results->fetch_row(); //hold total records in variable
    //break records into pages
    $total_pages = ceil($get_total_rows[0]/$item_per_page);

    //get starting position to fetch the records
    $page_position = (($page_number-1) * $item_per_page);

    //SQL query that will fetch group of records depending on starting position and item per page. See SQL LIMIT clause
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT , HotelAddress, HotelImages, Destination, StarRating  FROM HotelList where HotelCode= '$hotelc' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $page_position, $item_per_page" , $link);
    //Display records fetched from database.

    echo '<ul class="contents">';
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo  $row["HotelName"]. '. <strong>' .$row["HotelAddress"].'</strong> &mdash; '.$row["Destination"];
        echo '</li>';
    }  
    echo '</ul>';


    echo '<div align="center">';
    /* We call the pagination function here to generate Pagination link for us. 
    As you can see I have passed several parameters to the function. */
    echo paginate_function($item_per_page, $page_number, $get_total_rows[0], $total_pages);
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Page returns empty